# print media query not working on iOS(chrome, safari, mozilla)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

I'm trying to figure why the `@media print` doesn't seem to work on the iOS, on android the functionality works fine. Basically I've made a functionality to hide the contents that aren't part of the print

`body.printing *{display : none}`

and only display the contents that will be printed

`body.printing .print-me, body.printing .print-me > div{display : block}`.

```
$('.print-modal').on('click', function() {
    $('body').addClass('printing');
    window.print();
   $("body").removeClass("printing");
})
```

```css
@media print {
    /* Hide everything in the body when printing... */
    body.printing * { display: none; }
    /* ...except our special div. */
    body.printing .print-me, body.printing .print-me > div { display: block; }
}

@media screen {
    /* Hide the special layer from the screen. */
    .print-me { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: What is getting printed in `iOS`?

Comment: @sabithpocker the whole page

Comment: Don't even bother setting the `printing` class - that's the whole point of the `@media print`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the issue is, you are adding a class `printing` and removing the same class immediately. That's could be the reason.

Try changing the logic. You don't need to add a class for printing. Instead use print media query `@media print` to handle print logic.

```
$('.print-modal').on('click', function() {
    window.print();
})

@media print {
    /* Hide everything in the body when printing... */
    body * { display: none; }
    /* ...except our special div. */
    body .print-me, body .print-me > div { display: block; }
}

@media screen {
    /* Hide the special layer from the screen. */
    .print-me { display: none; }
}
```